# how to load a different html page without refreshing the page or changing the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load an html page without refreshing the page or changing its url.
So for example, If I am at `http://localhost/sample/home` and I want to navigate to contact us page, I click on the contact link and the contact page content gets loaded without refreshing the page or changing the url.

How this can be done?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 5):

Look into the use of [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

This allows you to load HTML from a URL, and display it in an element in your page.

Therefore you could do something like:

```
$("body").load("/sample/contactus");
```

---

However I wouldn't recommend this as its not great for SEO or accessibility. Also it wouldn't reduce load time because you still need to make a HTTP Request for a whole other page..

Answer (score 3):

Mock HTML:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="/contactus.html">Contact Us </a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#links > a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //so the browser doesn't follow the link

        $("#content").load(this.href, function() {
            //execute here after load completed
        });
    });
});
```

[jQuery `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
$('#content').load('ajax/contact.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/